# R beeswarm plot by grouping by rows?

Tags: r, plot

I am using R beeswarm library to plot my data.

When I am plotting my dataframe directly, it does nice plot by processing columns as separate classes and plotting them accordingly.

However, when I try to plot a transpose of the same dataframe, for some reason it flattens my dataframe before plotting it and plots all the classes aggregated.

Is this a normal behavior or a bug?

Is there a way to force beeswarm to use rows and not columns as the classes to group on?

**Edit**:
data is a 94 x 40 data frame with pretty much random numbers here are the commands:

`beeswarm(mydata, cex=0.4)`

`beeswarm(t(mydata), cex=0.4)`

and the resulting plots: 
[image: column-wise]
[image: row-wise]

Comment: Could you please post some example data?

Comment: @StephanKolassa: please see modifications

Comment: @Andrei: what is the reason that you'd like to transpose your original data? Your transposed data is probably a matrix, it should be of class data.frame. Probably something like "newdf<-data.frame(t(df))" would be needed.

Comment: @Andrei, excellent, glad that it works! Below I have put the different data classes of matrix and data.frame and the effect on a beeswarm in the answer box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this problem is due to your transposed data being of class matrix

**Example data**

```
dd<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,9), b=c(3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,9), c=c(5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,9,11,11,12))
```

This gives a nice plot for each column

```
beeswarm(dd, pch = 16, col = rainbow(8))
```

Now the data are transposed and of class matrix. A beeswarm will take all columns altogether as if it were one column

```
ndd<-t(dd)

beeswarm(ndd, pch = 16, col = rainbow(8))
```

But if the transposed data are converted to data.frame, this will display all columns separately:

```
df<-data.frame(t(dd))
colnames(df)<-c(letters[1:15])
beeswarm(df, pch = 16, col = rainbow(8))
```

[image]